# restrict GitHub API access with least privilege

Tags: git, api, github

We are using GitHub Enterprise appliance.
how to restrict GitHub Enterprise API access with least privilege, so that it wont get misused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a **personal access token** to limit the scope of the GitHub Enterprise API.

That way your automations consuming that token will have the API restricted to the scopes you selected in the creation time (e.g only able to interact with repos but not manage the orgas, etc), find more information in their documentation [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

Cheers

Comment: Tyanks for your quick response. However i am not sure while we are creating the personal access token what is the least privilege that we can give to them..

Comment: In the GitHub menu under settings/Developer settings, while creating the personal access token, it allows you to select only those specific permissions you need for your token, they are categorised by different scopes, i.e https://github.com/settings/tokens/new